# I got nothing in my grid view (C# dependency)

Tags: c#, datagridview, dependencies

I have a windows application using SqlDependency. This application represents a log monitor UI get the latest rows added in a specific table in the database and view it in a DataGridView
The code is realize the change in SQL Server but the DataGridView show nothing (No errors, and no data, just as many line as in datatable)

Here is my code

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int changeCount = 0;
        private const string tableName = "NhanVien";
        private const string statusMessage = "Đã có {0} thay đổi.";

        //' The following objects are reused
        //' for the lifetime of the application.
        private SqlConnection connection = null;
        private SqlCommand command = null;
        private DataSet dataToWatch = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }
        private bool CanRequestNotifications()
        {
            // In order to use the callback feature of the
            // SqlDependency, the application must have
            // the SqlClientPermission permission.
            try
            {
                SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
                perm.Demand();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            // To avoid storing the connection string in your code,
            // you can retrive it from a configuration file.
            // Return "Data Source=THU-PC\TINTIN;Initial Catalog=QLVT;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=kc;Pooling = false"
            return "Data Source=MSI;Initial Catalog=ChuyenDeCNPM;User ID=sa;Password=123;";
        }
        private string GetSQL()
        {
            return "select manv as [Mã NV],Ho as [       Họ],Ten as [Tên],phai as [Phái],diachi as [     Địa chỉ] from dbo.NhanVien";
        }
        private void nhanVienBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.nhanVienBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.chuyenDeCNPMDataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'chuyenDeCNPMDataSet.NhanVien' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.nhanVienTableAdapter.Fill(this.chuyenDeCNPMDataSet.NhanVien);
            if (CanRequestNotifications() == true)
                BatDau();
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Bạn chưa kích hoạt dịch vụ Broker", "Cảnh báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            // This event will occur on a thread pool thread.
            // It is illegal to update the UI from a worker thread
            // The following code checks to see if it is safe update the UI.
            ISynchronizeInvoke i = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;

            // If InvokeRequired returns True, the code is executing on a worker thread.
            if (i.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Create a delegate to perform the thread switch
                OnChangeEventHandler tempDelegate = new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                object[] args = new[] { sender, e };

                // Marshal the data from the worker thread
                // to the UI thread.
                i.BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);

                return;
            }

            // Remove the handler since it's only good
            // for a single notification
            SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;

            dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

            // At this point, the code is executing on the
            // UI thread, so it is safe to update the UI.
            ++changeCount;
            this.label1.Text = string.Format(statusMessage, changeCount);

            // Add information from the event arguments to the list box
            // for debugging purposes only.
            {
                var withBlock = this.ListBox1.Items;
                withBlock.Clear();
                withBlock.Add("Info:   " + e.Info.ToString());
                withBlock.Add("Source: " + e.Source.ToString());
                withBlock.Add("Type:   " + e.Type.ToString());
            }

            // Reload the dataset that's bound to the grid.
            GetData();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
           
                // Empty the dataset so that there is only
                // one batch worth of data displayed.
                dataToWatch.Clear();

                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.

                command.Notification = null;

                // Create and bind the SqlDependency object
                // to the command object.        

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) 
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataToWatch, tableName);
                DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dataToWatch;
                DataGridView1.DataMember = tableName;
            }    
                

                /*DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;*/
            
        }

        private void BatDau()
        {
            changeCount = 0;
            // Remove any existing dependency connection, then create a new one.
            SqlDependency.Stop(GetConnectionString());
            try
            {
                SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                connection.Open();
            }
            if (command == null)
                // GetSQL is a local procedure that returns
                // a paramaterized SQL string. You might want
                // to use a stored procedure in your application.
                command = new SqlCommand(GetSQL(), connection);

            if (dataToWatch == null)
                dataToWatch = new DataSet();
            GetData();
        }
        private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Update form = new Update();
            form.Show();
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(GetConnectionString());
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my datagridview after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzhTx.png)

I tried debug and saw that the datasource is set. But it's still empty in GridView
[image: This is debug]

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that i have TableAdapter and BindingSource connect with GridView [![like this][1]][1], so it's cause fault. If you delete all that, use datatable instead of dataset, the code will be like this:

```
private void GetData()
    {

            dt.Clear();

            // Make sure the command object does not already have
            // a notification object associated with it.

            command.Notification = null;

            // Create and bind the SqlDependency object
            // to the command object.        

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
            connection.Open();
            }
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
        
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        
    }
```

You should declare DataTable as global variable. Everything should work well. Good Luck!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aODka.png